# How do I use a public function inside and outside of a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jQuery plugin and need functions that can be called from inside as well as outside the plugin. Here is my code so far:

```
(function($){
 $.fn.bxSlider = function(options){

  var defaults = {
   mode : 'horizontal',
   speed : 500
  }

  var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

  var base = this;

  this.each(function(){   
   var someText = base.getText;
   console.log(someText);
  });

  this.getText = function(){
   return base.children().text();
  }

  return this;

 } 

})(jQuery);
```

When I call getText() from outside the plugin - it works just fine:

```
$(function(){
 var slider = $('ul').bxSlider();
 var text = slider.getText();
 $('body').append(text);
});
```

But when I try to call the function inside the plugin, I get a "function is not defined" error. Am I using the wrong syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling it *before* you've added it to that jQuery object.

Try this:

```
  var base = this;

  this.getText = function(){
   return base.children().text();
  }

  this.each(function(){   
   var someText = base.getText;
   console.log(someText);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're adding the method `getText` onto each instance, and trying to call it before definition.  You could either:

1. Switch the order of your `this.each` and `this.getText =` so that you assign `getText` first
2. Assign `getText` the same way you've assigned `bxSlider`, by extending `$.fn`.  This way it will be on the prototype of all jQuery objects.  You'll probably want to build in some logic to verify an error is thrown if you call `getText` before calling `bxSlider` on an object.